# dart http and python flask: difference between request.files and request.form?

Tags: dart, flask, httprequest, multipart

I'm sending a `MultipartRequest` with `Dart` and receiving it with `Flask`:

```dart
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
  ..files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('thumbnail', thumbnail))
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('video', videoPath));
print('request.files: ');
print(request.files);
var streamedResponse = await request.send();
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
```

Printing `request.files` shows that I have 2 `MultipartFiles`, as expected:

```
flutter: request.files:
flutter: [Instance of 'MultipartFile', Instance of 'MultipartFile']
```

Then, I process the request in `Flask`:

```py
@app.route('/addPost', methods=['POST'])
def addPost():
    print('request.form: ')
    print(request.form)
    print('request.files: ')
    print(request.files)
    video = request.files['video']
    thumbnail = request.files['thumbnail']
```

However, only 'video' is present in `request.files`, while 'thumbnail' is actually in `request.form`:

```
request.form: 
ImmutableMultiDict([('thumbnail', '<massive string here>')])
request.files: 
ImmutableMultiDict([('video', <FileStorage: 'trim.EE219D47-2D36-4A58-A242-4490C40F8A5F.MOV' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```

Furthermore, as described by [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37311), if I add a filename to the thumbnail `MultipartFile`, 'thumbnail' then shows up in `request.files`:

```dart
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
  ..files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'thumbnail',
    thumbnail,
    filename: 'placeholder_filename',
  ))
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('video', videoPath));
```

the prints from `Flask`:

```
request.form: 
ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.files: 
ImmutableMultiDict([('thumbnail', <FileStorage: 'placeholder_filename' ('application/octet-stream')>), ('video', <FileStorage: 'trim.E892CEB2-DD59-4F24-BB5F-6E8338E8C66B.MOV' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```

So, what's the difference between `request.files` and `request.form`, and how should I be using them?